# CodenameOne calling Start() method crashes app

Tags: codenameone, reload

In my application I am using a button to go back to the start screen by calling

```
newForm.removeAll();
Display.getInstance().lockOrientation(true);

hi.start();
```

from a different form.

That works ok, generally, but sometimes the app freezes and I have to close and restart it.

Is the freezing due to calling hi.start() from a different form?

Is calling hi.start() from a different from the best way to go back to the start screen?

Comment: As James said calling `start()` is probably not a great idea. However, the `lockOrientation()`  method will only work on Android. On iOS an app is either orientation locked or it isn't. You need to declare that in the build hints

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, Shai.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine the start method has more going on than just showing the opening form. The preferable way would be to build the form from scratch and then show it when you want to return to it. If you use showBack, it will use the opposite animation to transition to the form. This would use the least memory. You could subclass Form if you need special behavior.

Store the state of your start form with Preferences or Storage if there is dynamic content.

Comment: Many thanks for this excellent clarification, @James H. I already figured that the start method has a lot more going on under the hood....